# Python Printing Elements from a dictionary produces error

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I created this block of code for usernames which is read using a loop.

```
users = {
    'aeinstein': {
        'first':'albert',
        'last':'einstein',
        'location':'princeton'
        },
    'mcurie': {
        'first':'marie',
        'last':'curie',
        'location':'paris',
        }
    }

for username, user_info in users.items():
    print("\nUsername: " + username)
    full_name = user_info['first'], user_info['last']
    location = user_info['location']

    print("\tFull name:" + full_name.title())
    print("\tLocation:" + location.title())
```

Now, if you observe the following line in the for loop

```
full_name = user_info['first'], user_info['last']
```

I expect<sup>1</sup> this to append the value `albert einstein` and `marie curie`, but this produces the error

```
print("\tFull name:" + full_name.title())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'title'
```

but why is my method wrong and the following therefore correct...

```
full_name = user_info['first'] + " " + user_info['last']
```

to produce the following result

```
Username: aeinstein
    Full name:Albert Einstein
    Location:Princeton

Username: mcurie
    Full name:Marie Curie
    Location:Paris
```

---

<sup>1</sup>*From the comments:* so when you do say `print("hello", "world")` this type of string concatenation works right but not in the example that I have shown?

Comment: In the first one you are using a comma, therefore creating a tuple and

Comment: Do you understand what `full_name = user_info['first'], user_info['last']` is doing?

Comment: Because that's the Python synax - `+` operator is used for string concatenation, a comma creates a tuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542694/difference-between-using-commas-concatenation-and-string-formatters-in-python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `user_info['first'], user_info['last']` creates a tuple of two elements (in this case the elements are strings). Tuple object does not have the `title` method but if you concatenate with the plus operator like you do `user_info['first'] + " " + user_info['last']`, you create a String and not a tuple so you can use the title method

Answer (score 2):

By adding the `,` operator in `user_info['first'], user_info['last']` you are telling Python that you are giving it a tuple of two strings. By using the `+` operator, you are simply concatenating the two strings into one string.

Comment: so when you do say `print("hello", "world")` this type of string concatenation works right but not in the example that I have shown?

Comment: Actually you are printing a tuple when you say print("hello", "world")

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy No, you pass two arguments to the print function, which concatenates them.

Comment: Printing a tuple would be `print(("hello", "world"))`.

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy In case of Python 2 you are right, but then this would be less misleadingly written `print ("hello", "world")`. (With a space)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I couldn't find anywhere in the Python 2 documentation that tuples get concatenated, so I guess we're both right

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> full_name = user_info['first'], user_info['last']
> ```
>
> I expect this to append the value `albert einstein` and `marie curie` […]

Your expectation is wrong.

> but why is my method wrong and the following therefore correct...
>
> ```
> full_name = user_info['first'] + " " + user_info['last']
> ```

Because `+` is the concatenation operator for strings, and `,` is not.

Answer (score 1):

As replied by several others you need to use

full_name = user_info['first']+" "+ user_info['last']

OR

full_name = "%s %s" %(user_info['first'],user_info['last'])