# How do I print the values of a list in one line rather than separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For instance, instead of something like:

> My friends are Kate
>
> My friends are Matt

I want to print out:

> My friends are Kate, Matt

```
myFriends = []

def add_new_friend():
    while True:
        newFriend = input("Add your new friend (Enter blank to quit):")
        if newFriend == "":
            break
        elif newFriend == "check":
            check_friends()
        else:
            myFriends.append(newFriend)
            for friend in range(len(myFriends)):
                print(myFriends[friend])
```

Comment: You code does not produce either of those outputs.

Answer (score 4):

Build the whole string that you want to print using `join`, then invoke `print` once:

```
print("My friends are " + ", ".join(myFriends))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. You can use `str.format` combined with `', '.join` to print in the format you require.

```
myFriends = []

def add_new_friend():
    while True:
        newFriend = input("Add your new friend (Enter blank to quit):")
        if newFriend == "":
            break
        elif newFriend == "check":
            check_friends()
        else:
            myFriends.append(newFriend)
            print('My friends are: {0}'.format(', '.join(myFriends)))

add_new_friend()
```

Comment: The `{0}` is the last part of the format string. Does it have any advantages over a simple `+`, except that it is easier to change the formatting if the requirements change? *(it would be a perfectly valid reason, I see that. As soon as the OP wants to append a simple period, the `format` solution will become more concise)*

Comment: Some ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722105/format-strings-vs-concatenation), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619384/python-string-formatting-vs-concatenation)), including me, think `str.format` is more readable. This [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542726/9209546) gives all the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

```
for friend in myFriends:
  print(friend, end=', ')
```

which should give you this output ...

Kate, Matt,

Comment: Well, yes, we can. But... *should it* give this output?