# What is the difference between comma and plus in python print statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to understand the output of `print((x,y)*5)`. I wish to know what actually is happening behind the scenes. (To me, it seems as if it turned into a list. Am I right?)

```
x = 'Thank'
y = 'You'

print(x+y)
print(x,y)

print((x+y)*5) 
print((x,y)*5) #This one..
```

I am a beginner in Python and I'm asking a question for the first time ever. Please forgive me if this question seems naive. I tried Googling but it didn't help.

Comment: plus concatenate and the other just display the variables value

Comment: try that with int or floats , You'll understand

Comment: `x+y` concatenate and print it 5 times, while `x,y` are two seperate values and are multiplied 5 times alternatively and displayed as list. so its like `x` first then `y` at second place upto 5 times

Comment: `print("ab" + "ra" + "ca" + "da" + "bra")` vs `print("ab","ra","ca","da","bra")` vs `print("ab","ra","ca","da","bra", sep = "WUSH")` - seperate entities are printed with `sep` between - concattenated strings are printed as one concatted string. And printing tuples (not lists) should be obvious.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542694/difference-between-using-commas-concatenation-and-string-formatters-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x = 'Thank'
y = 'You'


# concatenation of string x and y which is treated as a single element and then 
# printed (Here, only a single argument is passed to the print function).
print(x+y)  
# Output: ThankYou  (Simple String concatenation)


# Here, two different arguments are passed to the print function.
print(x,y)  
# Output python 2: ('Thank', 'You')  (x and y are treated as tuple
# Output python 3: Thank You  (x and y are comma seperated and hence, 
# considered two different elements - the default 'sep=" "' is applied.)


# The concatenated result of (x + y) is printed 5 times.
print((x+y)*5) 
# Output: ThankYouThankYouThankYouThankYouThankYou  

# x and y are made elements of a tuple and the tuple is printed 5 times.
print((x,y)*5) 
# Output: ('Thank', 'You', 'Thank', 'You', 'Thank', 'You', 'Thank', 'You', 'Thank', 'You')
```

Comment: It would be worth explaining what is printed and why. You're halfway there.

Comment: Less then 10 months to skip using python 2.x: https://pythonclock.org/  - your answer is python 2 specific - the question is python 3, I edited the difference in. You can verify it using f.e. http://www.pyfiddle.io (switched to 3.x)

Comment: @PatrickArtner, Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my doubts! This is crystal clear to me now.

Comment: Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

plus act as concatenation operator if operands are string otherwise it acts as mathematical plus operator.Whereas comma in print function is used to separate the variables:In case of string , and + in print works as same but fundamentally they are different: + creates new object from operand whereas comma uses objects and did not create new :

```
print('Delhi'+'is capital')

print(2+6)

var1='Hello'
var2='!!'
print(var1,var2)
print(2,6)
```