# What is the difference between concatenating with a comma and plus

Tags: python, pycharm

can you please tell me what is the difference between , and + while concatenation?

```
num=0
print(num,'Hi')
print(num+'Hi')
```

So just wrote a program that doesn't make any sense.
So I want to know if you use the first option then it prints 0 Hi
but in the 2nd it shows an error.
This was just a meaningless code but when I write codes that involve int and str so when I use the 2nd one it shows cant concatenate str and int but the 1st option gives the right answer.
Can you tell me why in simple language and how using both options can change the output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between using commas, concatenation, and string formatters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542694/difference-between-using-commas-concatenation-and-string-formatters-in-python)

Comment: The thing to know is that `,` constructs a tuple. Try `>>> 1,2` in the interactive prompt. A tuple is one method to pass variable arguments in Python

Answer (score 2):

concatenation means you are combining both variables(only strings) into one. But when you use comma it prints both the output separately but you can't see it on the output console. concatenation can only be made between strings.

`num=0`
`print(num+'Hi')`

so this code will give you a error like this:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

because concatenation can only be made between two strings

Answer (score 1):

You are not really 'concatenating' when you say print(x, y).  You are just printing two strings.  Concatenating is when you add one string to another.  So for example you may want to do something like this (which is concatenation):

```
answer = "Here is your answer: "
if x = 1:
  answer = answer + "1"
if x = 2:
  answer = answer + "2"

print(answer)
```

By using the plus sign, you have changed the contents of the string named 'answer'.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. print(num, 'Hi') parses out a tuple and prints each item whereas print(num + 'Hi') attempts to combine an integer and a string, which is not possible.